# How to add on long click on floating action button in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I need to add two events on FAB, a single click and a long click. This is what I have tried:

```
@Composable
@ExperimentalFoundationApi
fun MyFAB() {
    FloatingActionButton(
        modifier = Modifier
            .combinedClickable(
                onLongClick = {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onLongClick") //Doesn't work
                },
                onClick = {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onClick") //Doesn't work
                }
            ),
        onClick = {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick") //Works
        }
    ) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
            contentDescription = "Add item"
        )
    }
}
```

When I use the [combinedClickable](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary.html#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).combinedClickable(kotlin.Boolean,%20kotlin.String,%20androidx.compose.ui.semantics.Role,%20kotlin.String,%20kotlin.Function0,%20kotlin.Function0,%20kotlin.Function0)) modifier none of the clicks works. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, the FloatingActionButton uses a [Surface](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#Surface(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,kotlin.Function0)) under the hood, which already has an assigned `clickable()` modifier.

Comment: You can create your own custom FloatingActionButton which e.g. uses a [Box](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#Box(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1)) under the hood with a `combinedClickable()` modifier.

Comment: Can you please show me an example of how to use a Box under the hood? Thanks.